# How to Copy Cookie to WKWebview in iOS?

Tags: cookies, xamarin.forms, wkwebview

I don't know how/which cookies are coming from which website. Because of that, I can't set manually the cookie names.

How can I get third party cookies to paste to a `WKWebview`? Here is my code but no chance.

My webview;

```cs
public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: "Uri",
            returnType: typeof(Uri),
            declaringType: typeof(CustomWebView),
            defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

My custom renderer (Shouldn't necessary an event per request? This method fires once in the first request);

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(HTMobile.iOS.WebViewRenderer))]
namespace HTMobile.iOS
{
    public class WebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomWebView, WKWebView>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                // Cookie
                var cookieUrl = new Uri("abc.com"); 
                NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.AcceptPolicy = NSHttpCookieAcceptPolicy.Always;
                var cookieJar = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
                cookieJar.AcceptPolicy = NSHttpCookieAcceptPolicy.Always;
                foreach (var aCookie in cookieJar.Cookies)
                {
                    cookieJar.DeleteCookie(aCookie);
                }

                var jCookies = UserInfo.CookieContainer.GetCookies(cookieUrl);
                IList<NSHttpCookie> eCookies =
                (from object jCookie in jCookies
                    where jCookie != null
                    select (Cookie)jCookie
                    into netCookie
                    select new NSHttpCookie(netCookie)).ToList();
                cookieJar.SetCookies(eCookies.ToArray(), cookieUrl, cookieUrl);

                // WebView Instance
                webView = new WKWebView(Frame, new WKWebViewConfiguration());
                SetNativeControl(webView);

                if (e.NewElement != null)
                {
                    Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl("abc.com")));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think an event should be fired per request and I should be able to get a cookie list for the visited page and then set it to my `WebView`.

Advise, please.

Comment: You can have a try with getting cookie by invoking [DecidePolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/webkit.wknavigationdelegate.decidepolicy?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) method from **WKNavigationDelegate** .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT, can you give a little example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a try with getting cookie by invoking [DecidePolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/webkit.wknavigationdelegate.decidepolicy?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) method from **WKNavigationDelegate** .

```
public class NavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
{
    NSMutableArray multiCookieArr = new NSMutableArray();

public override void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationResponse navigationResponse, [BlockProxy(typeof(Action))]Action<WKNavigationResponsePolicy> decisionHandler)
{

    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(12, 0))
    {
        WKHttpCookieStore wKHttpCookieStore = webView.Configuration.WebsiteDataStore.HttpCookieStore;
        Console.WriteLine("wKHttpCookieStore is :" + wKHttpCookieStore.GetDebugDescription());
        wKHttpCookieStore.GetAllCookies(cookies => {
            if(cookies.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (NSHttpCookie cookie in cookies)
                {
                    //NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.SetCookie(cookie);
                    Console.WriteLine("cookie is :" + cookie);
                }

            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        NSHttpUrlResponse response = navigationResponse.Response as NSHttpUrlResponse;
        NSHttpCookie[] cookiesAll = NSHttpCookie.CookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(response.AllHeaderFields, response.Url);
        foreach (NSHttpCookie cookie in cookiesAll)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Here is the cookie inside wkwebview is :" + cookie);
            NSArray cookieArr = NSArray.FromObjects(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, cookie.Domain, cookie.Path);
            multiCookieArr.Add(cookieArr);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("cookie is :" + cookiesAll);
    }

    decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicy.Allow);

    //base.DecidePolicy(webView, navigationResponse, decisionHandler);
}
```

In addition , using Renderer to [Customizing a WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview) you can refer to this doc .

```
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
{

    public HybridWebViewRenderer() : this(new WKWebViewConfiguration())
    {
    }

    public HybridWebViewRenderer(WKWebViewConfiguration config) : base(config)
    {   
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
          //...
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            this.NavigationDelegate = new NavigationDelegat();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Jiang! I have a question. Is your solution appropriate for CustomWebView?

Comment: @Erdogan Yeah , you can use it in CustomWebView . Also need to set `WKNavigationDelegate` for CustomWebView .

Comment: base.DecidePolicy(webView, navigationResponse, decisionHandler); line gives an error : You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method. What may be problem?

Comment: @Erdogan Oh, sorry. I forget to remove this line code. You can retry it after removing it.

Comment: Oh okay, but the cookies object always null. When I visit the web page on a web browser in my pc, there is no problem, also in android.

Comment: @Erdogan Okey , I will check it . If good news will share here .

Comment: Thank you, Jiang. I really need this in my application, waiting for your good news.

Comment: @Erdogan Hi , I have updated anaswer , you need to use differer ways to get cookie when ios is 12 or later . If answer be helpful , Thanks for marking it in advance.