# WKWebView open popup facebook auth window but dosen`t login Xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, webview, wkwebview, custom-renderer

I am making a cross-platform hybrid app, basically rescuing a website in IOS, with Xamarin. The problem is that within this website there is a "Login with Facebook" section and this is an API, it is NOT a JavaScript "window.open" method.
I would like to know if I am doing this correctly, since I have tried different methods, and none have worked for me. I have already tried implementing the following:

- WKWebViewRenderer with the CreateWebView () function and class (Actual code)
- WebViewRenderer <CustomWebView, WKWebView> with the DecidePolicy () function and class
- Basic WebView enabling JavaScriptEnable and JavaScriptCanOpenWindow
- The combinations between these
  Thank you very much in advance, I leave my CustomWebView.

Note: I can't use UIWebView, it's banned from AppStore

```
    using Foundation;
    using MobileApp.iOS.Name;
    using MobileApp.Models;
    using System;
    using UIKit;
    using WebKit;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebViewIOS), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
    namespace MobileApp.iOS.Name
    {
        public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
        {
            protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);

                WKWebView wKWebView = this;
                WKPreferences pref = new WKPreferences() { JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true, JavaScriptEnabled = true, };
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                config.Preferences = pref;
            
                if (NativeView != null)
                {
                    ((WKWebView)NativeView).UIDelegate = new MyWKUIDelegate();
                }
            }
        }

        public class MyWKUIDelegate : WKUIDelegate
        {
            public override WKWebView CreateWebView(WKWebView webView, WKWebViewConfiguration configuration, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, WKWindowFeatures windowFeatures)
            {
                var url = navigationAction.Request.Url;
                if (navigationAction.TargetFrame == null)
                {
                    webView.LoadRequest(navigationAction.Request);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, whether it's a popup login window, and what's the result of running the shared code?

Comment: I enter username and password, it asks me if I want to continue as x name and the pop-up window closes, leaving me exactly where I sent it to call and without having logged in ... If I accept the Facebook cockies, the next times I want to log in, it does nothing, just the screen goes white for 1 second and returns to normal, at the beginning of everything.

Comment: If want to use cookies in wkwebview, you could have a look at this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61828868/xamarin-wkwebview-and-cookies

Comment: I don't know if it's what I need, but I'll try ...

Comment: Okey, if works for you let me know that.

Comment: it didn't work :( I tried all the options and followed the examples in the link, but still it keeps doing the same

Comment: any news on this?

Comment: @GiovanniTrezzi no, nothing new, sorry man.