# Loading Custom WebView via calling a Delegate - Xamarin (iOS)

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I have 2 Custom WebViews in two different tabs. If I catch a specific URL from WebView 1, sending a message via message center to the second page and invoking the delegate. In this way, I can load the second WebView from Custom Renderer's side. It's very easy on the Android side.

How can I implement the WKWebView in the same concept?

Android side;
PCL;

```
public class CustomWebView : WebView
 {
     public delegate void NewNavigateDelegate(string parameter, Action<string> callback);
     public NewNavigateDelegate NewNavigateEvent;
    
     public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
         propertyName: "Uri",
         returnType: typeof(string),
         declaringType: typeof(CustomWebView),
         defaultValue: default(string));
    
    public string Uri
     {
         get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
         set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
     }
 }
    
  public partial class WebBrowserPage : ContentPage
     {
         public WebBrowserPage()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
    
             MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "MainWebView", (sender) =>
             {
                 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                 {
                     webView.NewNavigateEvent.Invoke("MainWebView", (args) =>
                     {
    
                     });
                 });
             });
         }
      }
```

WebViewRenderer;

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(WebViewRendererDroid))]
 namespace XamApp.Droid
 {
     public class WebViewRendererDroid : ViewRenderer<CustomWebView, Android.Webkit.WebView>
     {
         Context _context;
         public WebViewRendererDroid(Context context) : base(context)
         {
             AutoPackage = false;
             _context = context;
         }
    
  protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomWebView> e)
         {
             base.OnElementChanged(e);
    
             if (e.NewElement != null)
             {
                 #region Defualt Variables
                 var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
    
                 CustomWebView customView = (CustomWebView)e.NewElement;
    
                 webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    
                 webView.SetWebViewClient(new ClientWebView($"{js}"));
                 webView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    
                 webView.LoadUrl(customView.Uri);
                 SetNativeControl(webView);
    
                 CookieManager.Instance.SetAcceptThirdPartyCookies(Control, true);
                 #endregion
    
                 CustomWebView page = (CustomWebView)e.NewElement;
                 page.NewNavigateEvent += Navigate_OnDoing;
    
                 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "GoBack", (sender) =>
                 {
                     Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                     {
                         try
                         {
                             if (webView.CanGoBack() == true)
                                 webView.GoBack();
                         }
                         catch (Exception ex)
                         {
                         }
                     });
                 });
             }
    
             if (e.OldElement != null)
             {
                 CustomWebView page = (CustomWebView)e.NewElement;
                 page.NewNavigateEvent -= Navigate_OnDoing;
             }
         }
    
         void Navigate_OnDoing(string parameter, Action<string> action)
         {
             if (Control != null)
             {
                 var webView = (Android.Webkit.WebView)Control;
                 try
                 {
                         string url = "";
    
                         if (parameter == "OrderWebView")
                             url = "https://.....com/Hesap/Siparislerim";
                         if (parameter == "MainWebView")
                             url = "https://......com";
    
                         webView.LoadUrl(url);
                     action("ok");
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

ClientWebView;

```
class ClientWebView : WebViewClient
     {
         string _javascript;
         public ClientWebView(string javascript)
         {
             this._javascript = javascript;
         }
    
         public override async void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
         {
             string cookies = CookieManager.Instance.GetCookie(url);
    
             if (AppSettings.isLogin == false && cookies != null && cookies.Contains("Identity.Application")) // logon
             {
                 MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "OrderWebView");
    
                 base.OnPageFinished(view, url.Replace("giris?ReturnUrl=%2F", ""));
    
                 AppSettings.isLogin = true;
             }
             else
                 base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
    
             AllowCookies(view);
         }
    
         private void AllowCookies(Android.Webkit.WebView view)
         {
             CookieManager.Instance.Flush();
             CookieManager.AllowFileSchemeCookies();
             CookieManager.SetAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
             CookieManager.Instance.AcceptCookie();
             CookieManager.Instance.AcceptThirdPartyCookies(view);
             CookieManager.Instance.SetAcceptCookie(true);
             CookieManager.Instance.SetAcceptThirdPartyCookies(view, true);
         }
    }
```

---

iOS side;

Custom Renderer;

```
   [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
    namespace HTMobileMultiple.iOS
    {
        public class CustomWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomWebView, WKWebView>
        {
                WKWebView webView;
                protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomWebView> e)
                {
                    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    
                    if (Control == null)
                    {
                        var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                        webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                        webView.NavigationDelegate = new NavigationDelegate(Element);
                        SetNativeControl(webView);
                    }
    
                    if (e.NewElement != null)
                    {
                    Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(Element.Uri)));
                    webView.NavigationDelegate = new NavigationDelegate(Element);
                    SetNativeControl(webView);
                }
            }
        }
    
     public class NavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
        {
            private CustomWebView element;
    
            public NavigationDelegate(CustomWebView element)
            {
                this.element = element;
            }
    
            [Export("webView:didFinishNavigation:")]
            public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {
                string url = webView.Url.ToString();
    
                if (AppSettings.isLogin == false) // logon
                {
                    // I'm trying to send to the OrderWebView page and invoke to load the changed URL just like on the android side but don't know how to call/trigger the OrderWebView's load method 
                    MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "OrderWebView");
                }
        }
```

OrderWebViewPage;

```
   MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "OrderWebView", (sender) =>
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        // NewNavigateEvent is always null??
OrderWebView.NewNavigateEvent?.Invoke(OrderWebView.Uri.Uri.Trim().ToLower(), (args) =>
                        {
                            string callBack = args;
                        });
                    });
                });
```

Comment: is there a specific part of this that you're stuck on doing with WKWebView?

Comment: Shortly, what I need; Navigating a custom webview to a new url from PCL side when I want. As you can see, I can do this via an event that I created Android custom webview. How can I achive this on the iOS side? I don’t have an idea @Jason

Comment: @Erdogan Hi, why not realoding only in one webview when url be updated?

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT, Because I have a few tabs and some tabs requires login. At first opening, 2 tab's webview is redirecting to login page because of user is not logon yet and If user login from a tab, I need to redirect other page webviews login to account or bonuses page.

Comment: @Erdogan Okey, how about store cookies in webview, and get it from another webview.? Have a try with this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61828868/xamarin-wkwebview-and-cookies

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT thanks, but I already manage the cookies. Just don't know how to trigger a webview from PCL side when I want.

Comment: @Erdogan In the `Subscribe` method of `OrderWebViewPage`, whether the `OrderWebVie` also is null?