# How to Manually set cookies to WKWebViewRenderer in Xamarin forms IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer

I am working on Xamarin forms, I am trying to load a authenticated webview, I have Initialized Source and Cookies Properties in ViewModel. In Android its working fine, but in IOS authenticated webView is not loaded.

I tried by adding Custom WebView control with custom WkWebViewRenderer to load a WebView. I am confused on how to set Cookies Manually in WkWebViewRenderer

Answer (score 0):

> In Android its working fine, but in IOS authenticated webView is not
> loaded.

This reason should be the [ATS (App Transport Security)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preventing_insecure_network_connections) limitation of iOS. ATS is a security feature introduced by Apple in iOS 9. It will prevent connections that do not meet the minimum security requirements. You can add the following code in the `Info.plist` file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

> how to set Cookies Manually in WkWebViewRenderer

You can refer to the answer in issue: [Xamarin WKWebView and Cookies.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61828868/xamarin-wkwebview-and-cookies)